# vb.net DataGridView last row heigth not work

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, row, height

```
Dim lr As Integer = DataListInfo1.Rows.Count - 1
Dim rowHeigthSum As Integer

For n = 0 To lr
    rowHeigthSum += DataListInfo1.Rows(n).Height
Next n

lr = DataListInfo1.Rows.Count - 1
DataListInfo1.Rows(lr).Height = CInt(DataListInfo1.Height) - rowHeigthSum
```

[image: DataGridViewDisplay]

I'm using vb.net 2022... what I want to do here is to change the height of the last row to fit the height of the DataGridView.

but not work, like the image below, but still like the image above.

note :
DataListInfo1.Rows.Count = 4

lr = 2

rowHeghtSum = 87...
DataListInfo1.Rows(0).Heght = 29... DataListInfo1.Rows(1).Heght = 29... DataListInfo1.Rows(2).Heght = 29...

last row in DataGridViw (DataListInfo1.Rows(3).Heght = 17)

DataGridViw Heght (DataListInfo1.Heght = 215)

need to change height of last row in DataGridViw => DataListInfo1.Rows(3).Heght from 17 to 128 to fit to bottom of DataGridViw but the last row height still in 17..

[image: DataGridViewLastRowHeigth]

[image: BorangThailand]

Comment: Did you debug your code and see what the actual numbers are?

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. Please edit the question to provide all relevant information, where it will also be more readable.

Comment: [How to set first row height of DataGridView in Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74285730/7444103)

Comment: That's an odd display choice. Why not just set the `.Dock` property of the DGV to `Fill`, so it fills the parent container. Why is having the last row "fill" your requirement?

Comment: sorry everyone... now I got where my mistake was... first, in DataGridView properties, just set ColumnHeadersVisible and RowHeadersVisible to false.... before this, in the DataGridView Properties, I changed the AutoSizeRowsMode to true.... when i chose AutoSizeRowsMode to false... its work... thankyou...

Comment: I need to print the DataGridView into an A4 size form, and the form has an area available to print the DataGridView